# ¿Cómo agrupar por fecha en el admin de django?

Tags: python, django

Requiero agrupar el listado de un model en el admin de django por fecha.

Actualmente tengo lo sugiente:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return QueryModel.objects.all().extra(
        select={'day': 'date( date_created )'}).values('datetime')
```

Pero recibo el siguente error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 1):

Tu método `get_queryset` está bien escrito PERO, suponiendo que estás realizando la consulta en un Manager, deberías devolver un `QuerySet` y con tu método estás devolviendo un `ValuesQuerySet`. Esto se produce cuando has añadido el `.values('datetime')`. Si lo quitas debería funcionarte

Comment: Si funciona pero si lo quito ya no puedo agrupar por fecha. Existe alguna alternativa?

Answer (score 1):

Al definir tu área de administración, puedes usar la propiedad `ModelAdmin.date_hierarchy` que usa campos tipo `DateField` o `DateTimeField`, y crea un filtro por Año, Mes y Día en la parte superior de la lista de registros:

```
class EnvioModuloAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('lote',  'mac', 'recibido_mac', 'paquetes', 'formatos')
    list_filter = ['mac', 'lote__distrito']
    date_hierarchy = 'recibido_mac'
```

El resultado es algo así:

### Por año

[image: Filtro por Año]

### Por mes

[image: Filtro por mes]

### Por días

[image: Filtro por días]

La documentación, versión 1.10 https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.date_hierarchy.